# MySQL GROUP BY…exclude values in other field

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

i have a problem with a MySQL query for my statistic-page. I want to use a query similar to the following to retrieve all rows to "*version*" but i want to exclude values in other field "*platform*" if is not the same value.

**Example values:**

```
| platform | version | ...
----------------------
| Windows  | 1.0.1   |
| Windows  | 1.0.1   |
| Windows  | 1.0.1   |
| Windows  | 1.0.2   |
| Windows  | 1.0.3   |
| Linux    | 1.0.1   |
| Linux    | 1.0.1   |
| Linux    | 1.0.2   |
| Mac      | 1.0.1   |
| Mac      | 1.0.1   |
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    platform,
    version,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
    user
GROUP BY
    version
```

**Result:**

```
| platform | version | count |
------------------------------
| Windows  | 1.0.1   | 7     |
| Windows  | 1.0.2   | 2     |
| Windows  | 1.0.3   | 1     |
```

**I need the following result:**

```
| platform | version | count |
------------------------------
| Windows  | 1.0.1   | 3     |
| Windows  | 1.0.2   | 1     |
| Windows  | 1.0.3   | 1     |
| Linux    | 1.0.1   | 2     |
| Linux    | 1.0.2   | 1     |
| Mac      | 1.0.1   | 2     |
```

I hope you can help me... and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need the right `group by` clause:

```
SELECT platform, version, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM user
GROUP BY platform, version;
```

Your query is not actually syntactically correct SQL. The column `platform` is in the `SELECT` but it is not in the `GROUP BY`.  Almost any database other than MySQL would correctly return an error.

Comment: So every select column should be included in the group by ? Just learning a lot from your answers sorry for bothering.

Comment: @Noob . . . All columns in the select should either be columns in the `group by` or use aggregate functions (`sum()`, `avg()`, and so on).